# when a button is pressed in first activity the corresponding song should be played in second activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

Am new to android.Here is my question, I have 10 buttons.When button1 is clicked the corresponding song of the button1 should be played in next activity, which contains only play and stop buttons. similarlly, for the rest of the buttons.
I tried and am not getting exactly.

**Edit:**

Here's the code. Now the problem is, whatever the button is press, it only plays the first song "enno".

Below is the code of 1st activity "ButtonMenuActivity".

```
package com.example.button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class ButtonMenuActivity extends Activity 
{

    private MediaPlayer mp;


    Button b1, b2, b3, b4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.button_menu);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        createListeners();

    }

    private void createListeners() {
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startSecondActivity(1);
            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startSecondActivity(2);
            }
        });

        b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startSecondActivity(3);
            }
        });

        b4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startSecondActivity(4);
            }
        });
    }

    private void startSecondActivity(int buttonNum) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("BUTTONNUMBER", buttonNum);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

2nd activity code:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity 
{
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    //private int currentSong = 0;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int number = intent.getIntExtra("BUTTON NUMBER", 1);

          TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
          tv.setText(String.valueOf(number));

          if (number == 1) {
                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SecondActivity.this, R.raw.enno);

            } else if (number == 2) {
                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SecondActivity.this, R.raw.lad);


            } else if (number == 3) {
                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SecondActivity.this, R.raw.meres);


            } else if (number == 4) {
                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SecondActivity.this, R.raw.pookal);


                // Defaults 
            } else {
                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SecondActivity.this, R.raw.enno);


            }

            mPlayer.start();
        }
     @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();

            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.stop();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the code you've tried and explain where/what is/isn't working if you'd like help

Comment: See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Use intent.putExtra to communicate between Activities, with that You can translate the URL of Your song to the next Activity where You play the sound...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should add extras to your Intent? In another Activity you will get it.

```
...
intent.putExtra(KEY,VALUE);
```

In second activity

getIntent().getExtra(KEY)

Answer (score 0):

2nd activity code.

```
 public class SecondActivity extends Activity 
    {
        private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
        //private int currentSong = 0;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.second);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            int number = intent.getIntExtra("BUTTON NUMBER", 1);

              TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
              tv.setText(String.valueOf(number));

              if (number == 1) {
                    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SecondActivity.this, R.raw.enno);

                } else if (number == 2) {
                    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SecondActivity.this, R.raw.lad);


                } else if (number == 3) {
                    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SecondActivity.this, R.raw.meres);


                } else if (number == 4) {
                    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SecondActivity.this, R.raw.pookal);


                    // Defaults 
                } else {
                    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SecondActivity.this, R.raw.enno);


                }

                mPlayer.start();
            }
         @Override
            protected void onStop() {
                super.onStop();

                if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mPlayer.stop();
                }
            }
    }
```